# Alluvial diagram in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to create a fairly complex Alluvial diagram, similar to the one below:
[image]

I have a very strong preference for doing it in Matlab, but I haven't found any hints as to whether that's possible or not, and how - do you know?

If it is not possible in Matlab, which is the easiest and most comfortable alternative software?

Comment: It is *possible*, but there is not a function for it. You can code it. Also a quick Google search shows that this is not what an "spaghetti plot" is. Not sure if its name though

Comment: This is called an [Alluvial diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alluvial_diagram) or [Sankey diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sankey_diagram) not a "spaghetti plot", and there is no native MATLAB function to produce them, but you might want to search File Exchange, which has [at least one submission](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/26573-drawsankey) on the topic

Comment: Thanks, I will check that submission!

Comment: If you are ok with python, there is a package that might be useful: https://github.com/j-i-l/pyAlluv